# What's the different use IP directly and config the local host?

Tags: http, networking

I try to use IP directly access a URL by HTTP protocol, there are two methods here:

1. Use the URL which the domain replace with its IP
2. Config the IP and domain pair in local host of system

When the http request arrived the server, from the point of the server view, what's the different between the both request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be no difference to the server.  It is up to the client to resolve domain names to their IP addresses and there are a few ways to do that.  One is to use a DNS server, another is to use the hosts file.

To add on, the domain is most certainly sent in the HTTP request.  The browser (or other HTTP client) is responsible for that.  If you use the IP, then no domain will arrive at the server, meaning it will serve up whatever is configured as the default content for the IP.  The domain info is what allows the server to server multiple domains on a single IP.

Comment: My colleague said that the http request could carry domain info when use local host, if I use IP in URL only, the server would never know the URL's domain. I Just want to confirm is it true?

Comment: @sunjinbo -- This is true, if you use the IP, the web server will not know which domain you are attempting to access.  One small thing to note here is that it really comes down to how the web server is configured.  If the web server is configured for only a single domain on an IP, then it is irrelevant.  However, most hosts share an IP with multiple domains, in which case it would have no idea which to server up if you used just the IP.  So, yes, when you access by URL, the URL (and full path) is included in the request.

Comment: Forgot to add this for a quick reference...
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers#request_context
Look at the host field in the HTTP request header.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a Client connects to a Server.

First thing your computer does, is to analize the address you input.
If you wrote an IP, nothing to do now. If you wrote a domain, it will 'resolve' domain.

Resolving domain (DNS) means to 'translate' your URL into an IP. When computer resolves the domain, it will **only use** the new IP it got.

Client is sending packages with meta-data, that includes where this package is from (client's ip), where it may reach (server's ip), destin port etc.

**Domain is not included** on network packages.
Only IPs are included.
That means the **server could never know** if user connected to it using a domain or its ip directly.

Comment: My opinion is the same as yours, but my CDN colleague said that if I use IP not domain to access a CDN URL, they don't know where to find the source station of the URL. It's seems network packages may contains Domain info.

Comment: @sunjinbo in which package's section my I find domain?